# How to pass argument to proxy.ModifyResponse

Tags: go

Im using proxy.ModifyResponse

Is it possible to pass an argument to ModifyResponse

It's called like this

```
proxy.ModifyResponse = UpdateResponse
```

The definiton only seems to take *http.Response as an agrument

```
func UpdateResponse(resp *http.Response) error {

}
```

what would I do if i want to access another variable from outside?

Comment: Some possible answers: use a [closure](https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/25), use a method value for the update function, use a package level  variable.  Edit the question to show the context where the "outside" variable is declared.